# Parsing XML file with F# linq to XML

Tags: xml, f#, linq-to-xml

F# newbie

I have 2 XML files in 2 folders `c:\root\a\file.xml` and `c:\root\b\file.xml`

They have identical structure:

```
<parent>
   <property name="firstName">Jane</property>
   <property name="lastName">...</property>
   <property name="dateOfBirth">...</property>>
</parent>
```

I need to chose the file which property node with name `firstName` has the value Jane.

In F# (possibly by using `System.Xml.Linq`)
I have tried several solutions but none working so far. Anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It would be useful if you could show some code that you tried - someone can then explain what is the problem, so you can learn more than when someone just posts code that works. Anyway, you'll need to reference some assemblies with the `System.Xml.Linq` and open the namespace first. In F# interactive, you can write it like this (in F# project, just use *Add Reference* dialog):

```
#r "System.Core.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open System.Xml.Linq
```

When using XLinq in F#, you need a simple utility function for converting strings to `XName` object (which represents an element/attribute name). There is an implicit conversion in C#, but this sadly doesn't work in F#.

```
let xn s = XName.Get(s)
```

Then you can load your XML document using the `XDocument` class and use `Element` method to get a single "parent" element. Then you can call `Elements` to get all nested "property" elements:

```
let xd = XDocument.Load("file.xml")
let props = xd.Element(xn "parent").Elements(xn "property")
```

Now you can search the elements to find the one element with the specified attribute value. For example using `Seq.tryFind` (which also allows you to handle the case when the element is not found):

```
let nameOpt = props |> Seq.tryFind (fun xe -> 
  xe.Attribute(xn "name").Value = "firstName")
```

Now, the value `nameOpt` is of type `option<XElement>` so you can pattern match on it to see if the element was found (e.g. `Some(el)`) or if it wasn't found (`None`).

**EDIT:** Another way to write this is to use sequence expressions and then just take the first element (this doesn't handle the case when element is not found):

```
let nameEl = 
  seq { for el in xd.Element(xn "parent").Elements(xn "property") do
          if xe.Attribute(xn "name").Value = "firstName" then yield xe }
  |> Seq.head
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid! I thought the point of using f# ``query {}``expressions and linq were, that you could abstract from the data source. So - impossible as I deem it - is there no way to do a standard ``query { for foo in xmlBar do ... }`` kind of thing?

Comment: Note you also need to reference System.Xml if it is not already referenced

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to use LINQ for this.  Here's one way to do it:

```
open System.Xml.XPath

let getName (filename:string) =
  let xpath = XPathDocument(filename).CreateNavigator()
  let node = xpath.SelectSingleNode(@"parent/property[@name='firstName']")
  node.Value

let files = [@"c:\root\a\file.xml"; @"c:\root\b\file.xml"]
let fileForJane = files |> List.find (fun file -> getName file = "Jane")
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can mix kvb's solution with (?) operator:

```
let (?) (fname: string) (nodeName: string) : string =
  let xpath = XPathDocument(fname).CreateNavigator()
  let node = xpath.SelectSingleNode(@"parent/property[@name='"^nodeName^"']")
  node.Value;;

val ( ? ) : string -> string -> string

> "i:/a.xml"?firstName;;
val it : string = "Jane"
```

Comment: Don't understand.  I can't see which operator in the symbol and operator reference this is.  Can you provide reference?

Answer (score 2):

I Like this approach better

```
#r "System.Core.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open System.Xml.Linq

let xn s = XName.Get(s)

let xd = XDocument.Load("file.xml")
let fnp = xd.Descendants(xn "property")
        .Where(fun (p : XElement) -> p.Attribute(xn "name").Value = "firstName")
        .Single()
```